# Counting string sequence inside a cell

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have a string such as "0000xxx0xxx0xx00xxxxxx0xx0xxxxx" in an Excel Cell

I want to count how many times a sequence of more than three "x" appears, in other words, how many times a sequence such as "xxx" or "xxxx" and so on appears in this cell.

The output would be 4 times for this example.

Comment: For the sake of alternatives: `=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]"))`. Btw, you mentioned *"more than three"* which does not equal 4. You probably meant 3 or more...

Comment: @JvdV and you are not putting that as an answer......why?

Comment: Yours just seems like the way to go @ScottCraner, but couldn't help myself....just a Filterxml fan here :)

Comment: I would argue that even if mine is `the way to go` for this question, as you stated, future viewers may find yours helpful in solving their specific problem that mine does not.  As such it deserves to be written up as an answer. @JvdV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=(LEN("0"&A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("0"&A1,"0xxx","0")))/3
```

[image]

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of alternatives:

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[string-length(.)>2]"))
```

[image]

`FILTERXML` is available from Excel 2013 onwards (except Excel Online and Excel for Mac).